# Can't play .MP4 files on my android phone

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have an LG l33l. I recently recorded a video on my computer using Bandicam, in the .mp4 file. I edit my videos on my phone, so as usual, i try to take the recorded .mp4 file and send it to my phone. (My phone is connected to my computer with a USB cord.) So I send it and it completely sends. I unhook my phone and go to play it on my phone. But when I do I get this error message "unsupported format" I dont know what to do from here. Please help. Sorry if my explanation was confusing, ask me any questions you need to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try with VLC for Android. If not playing, then your mp4 is not compliant. MP4 is like a nut which contains a video stream and an audio stream. Of one these are not compliant in your video. Encode in mp4 with AAC and AVC for audio/video to be compliant with all devices.